# Hyper-V expand virtual hard drive size

Tags: hyper-v

I'm running a virtual machine (Hyper-V) on an Windows Server 2008 R2 64-bit machine. The virtual machine is also a Windows Server 2008 R2 64-bit.

The hard drive is a dynamically expanding virtual hard drive of 45 GB, but when I log in on the machine the hard drive is about 20 GB (the initial size). The drive is almost out of space and does not seem to increase automatically.

**EDIT:** I forgot to mention that I recently expanded the virtual drive. Thanks for pointing that out.

What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found [the answer](http://www.petri.co.il/expanding-virtual-hard-disks-with-hyper-v.htm). Use the Disk Management snap-in from the Computer Management tool to expand the partition within Windows.

**EDIT:** Yes, yes, I know, it was silly of me to forget that I had to expand the partition on the virtual machine if I expand the virtual drive.

Comment: Yes, and that is totally unrelated to Hyper-V... the same would happen on a physical machine when you run out of the original partition.

Comment: -1 This is not only completely unrelated to Hyper-V's operation, but you didn't mention that you resized the VHD. The VHD is either *not Dynamically Expanding* or you choose to configure a partition within the VHD less than the maximum size of the VHD.

Comment: I edited the question.